What the closure of the graph of $f(x) = \begin{cases}x\sin(\frac 1x) & x \ne 0,\\ 1 & x = 0\end{cases}$ defined on reals?
Since $f$ is defined at $x = 0$ its range looks like either $(y, 1]$ or $[y, 1]$. If it is the latter it would be the smallest closed set containing the graph. The function seems to hover in the range $(0, -0.5)$ for values in $(-0.5, 0.5)$ ignoring $x = 0$. But I am having difficulty pinning down this $y$-value precisely. How do we find $y$?
edit:
I tried adopting a similar looking proof for a simpler function $f(x) = x\sin(\frac 1x),  x \ne 0.$
For any point $(0, t)$ with $-x \le t \le x$ meaning $-1 \le \frac tx \le 1$ choose $y > 0$ s.t. $\sin y = \frac tx.$ Let $k = \frac tx.$
For any neighborhood $N$ of $(0, k)$ choose $\epsilon > 0$ with $B((0, k), \epsilon) \subseteq N$.
By Archimdean $\exists n$ with $n > \frac{1}{2\pi \epsilon}$ meaning $\frac{1}{2n\pi} < \epsilon$.
Now the distance from $(0, k)$ to $(\frac{1}{2n\pi + y}, \sin(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2n\pi + y}})) = (\frac{1}{2n\pi + y}, \sin(2n\pi + y)) =  (\frac{1}{2n\pi + y}, k)$ is $\frac{1}{2n\pi + y}  < \frac{1}{2n\pi} < \epsilon$ and so we have found a point inside $B((0, k), \epsilon)$ so that this point is inside $N$ implying $N$ meets the graph so that $(0, k)$ is in the closure of the graph.
Thus we have a segment $S$ that joins $(0, -1)$ with $(0, 1).$ Since the graph is closed, the closure of the graph is the union of the graph itself and $S$.

The graph of $f$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Are you instead looking for the range of $f$?

I don't know what you mean by "this $y$-value." Do you mean the point the graph seems to be approaching as your inputs get closer to the origin? If so, just find
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} x \sin \frac 1 x
$$
You can show this to be zero.

I might be very confused right now. Let's disregard what is in the body of the question and start over. I need to find the smallest closed set that contains the graph of $f$ or show the graph is in the intersection of all closed sets or maybe even show the graph contains all its limit points.

The graph is closed as the function is continuous. However the range does not contain $1.$ The range is of the form $[y,1),$ as the minimal value $y$ is attained in the interval $[0,\pi^{-1}].$

I see. I forgot what the graph of a function was, a cross product of two sets. I was looking at the plot of $f$ and somehow thought of an interval. Can we say the graph is the smallest set that contains itself?

@RyszardSzwarc The function is not continuous: $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 0 \neq 1 = f(0)$. You may have read too quickly and thought $f$ was defined as $f(0)=0$. So $1$ is certainly in the image, and the closure is the graph plus the point $(0,0)$.

@user1033615 "The smallest set that contains itself" either does not exist (if by "contains itself" you mean "is an element of itself"), or is the empty set (if by "contains itself" you mean "is a subset of itself"). Either way, I do not think you are saying what you really mean.

@ArturoMagidin, I edited my OP. Please, see if it makes any kind of sense.

You are still confusing the graph, which is a subset of the plane, with the image, which is a subset of the line. You need to decide which one you are talking about. And you need to stop using the title as part of the post. The post should be self-contained, and the title should ask something different. Right now, your post by itself is unintelligible because the question you are apparently trying to ask in the title, not in the post.

In the edit I am talking about the tuples, though. Aren't they in the graph?

The graph of $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$ is not closed, as it has $(0,0)$ as a limit point, but not the point itself. It also does not, as you claim, contain $S$; you seem to be confusing $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$, which always lies between the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ (and hence its closure is contained in the region bounded by those two lines), with the function $y= \sin(1/x)$. This is a mess.

Call the graph $X$. Since $X \subseteq X$, we have that $X \subseteq \overline{X}$ granted $X$ is closed. Plus we have to make sure the closure is not missing any other limit points. You said the only other point is $(0, 0)$. So we have to prove 1. graph is closed 2. $(0, 0)$ is a limit point. Is that correct so far?

Since $X$ is closed and is a subset of itself it is a candidate for being a closure, but it might be missing some limit points. I think it sounds better.

"we have that $X\subseteq\overline{X}$ granted $X$ is closed".  Huh? Every set is contained in its closure. "granted $X$ is closed" is nonsense. "plus we make sure the closure is not missing any other limit points" is nonsense: by definition, the closure is closed, and closed sets always contain all their limit points. "is that correct so far?" No, pretty much everything after $X\subseteq \overline{X}$ is nonsense.

I tried here and I am definitely not understanding something here. Can you simply write down the proof?

"the proof" of what? you have yet to state something sensible, let alone true, to be proven. You haven't even bothered to fix the confusion on whether you are working with $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ or with $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$.

I need an answer and elaboration for the following: https://imgur.com/a/5Ilow6v

@ArturoMagidin I have overlooked that the value at $0$ was $1, $ instead of $0.$
